# ABP framework - Best way to ValidateModel() and show success message

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages, abp

**Context**: Web application developed with ASPNet Core over ABP 2.9 framework (Razor pages).

I need to validate a model (it implements `Validate(...)` from `IValidatableObject` and calls the application service to perform some validations), then call an application service, and finally show a success message (with the same look & feel as  `abp.notify.success(...)`).

**Purpose** of this post: To validate whether I am following the best practices or doing things in the correct way with ABP framework. If so, there are some suggestions to ABP team.

**What I've tried**:

1.- First, I tried submitting the form, but I didn't find an easy way to show the success message (like `abp.notify.success` ones) from the server method: `public virtual async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()`.

*It would be nice to have a simple way to send client messages (like `abp.notify.success` ones) from server side. Maybe there is a way and I didn't find it.*

2.- Second, I tried to cancel form submission and peform validation in client side, call the application service and show the message, also from client side. The issue here is that validations on `public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)` method were not executed from client side calling `form.valid()`.

*Possible improvement to ABP framework would be to enable an easy way to perform same server `DataValidation()` from client side. Maybe it exists and I didn't find it.*

3.- Finally, I did the following:

a) Server side: to perform `ValidateModel()` and call the application service ([see cshtml.cs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNThd.png)).

b) Client Side: avoid form submission and submit it with ajax, and finally show the success message with `abp.notify.success(...))` ([see javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xw8i.png)).

---

Here are the **questions** related to previous issues. I appreaciate your comments or suggestions:

1.- Is there any better way to perform this scenario using ABP framework utils?

2.- Am I following the best practices? (placing the classes and logic in the correct layers)

- DTO with data annotations in Application.Contracts layer.
- DTOValidator class that inherits from DTO and `IValidatableObject` and implements `Validate(...)` method in Application.Contracts layer. This is to keep simple DTOs between client and application services.
- Model class that inherits from DTOValidator and is binded to form in .cshtml.cs (Example: `public class IndexPolicies : UpdatePolicyDtoValidator {}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with another issue I have found a solution that solves the problem taking full advantage of the ABP framework::

a) Server side: to perform ValidateModel() and call the application service (same as described on my third try).

b) Client Side: to use a simple button instead of submit one and call `abpAjaxForm(options)` with `abp.notify.success()` on success function. Then submit the form:

```
var _defaultPoliciesForm = $("#DefaultPoliciesForm");
var _saveButton = $("#SaveButton"); 

_saveButton.click(function (e) {
    var options = {
        beforeSubmit: function (arr, form) {
            _saveButton.buttonBusy(true);
        },
        success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, form) {
            abp.notify.success(l("UpdatedSuccessfully"));
        },
        complete: function (jqXhr, status, form) {
            _saveButton.buttonBusy(false);
        }
    }
    _defaultPoliciesForm.abpAjaxForm(options);
    _defaultPoliciesForm.submit();
});
```

Hope it can be useful to others with the same issue. Anyway, I remember my suggestions to ABP team:

- *Ability to send client messages like `abp.notify.success(...)` ones from server side.*
- *Ability to perform same server validation as `DataValidation()` from client side*

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel form submission and directly call application service. Then use DataAnnotations to validate your dto. If you need custom logic in validation, you can validate it in application service method (or create a custom DataAnnotation).

See https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-1?UI=MVC#dynamic-javascript-proxies for best way to call application service from javascript side.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have tested your suggested solution (directly call application services and validate DTO with custom DataAnnotation) but I am also facing an issue: 

Validation runs twice (I guess when calling HttpApi and when calling application service) and this is not optimal in some cases (like mine). 

On the other hand, perform the validation in the application service method is not what I was looking for.

Do you see any other possible solution?

Does my third alternative broke any ABP framework guideline?